# How to use (group by) and (order by) together?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have next scope, that groups objects by months of `customer_order_date`.

```
scope :grouped_by_months, -> {
    group("DATE_TRUNC('year', customer_order_date),
    DATE_TRUNC('month', customer_order_date)")
}
```

It work perfectly.

I need to add `order('customer_order_date desc')` in this scope, but all times when I try, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:
column "orders.customer_order_date" must appear in the
GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How I can add order by `customer_order_date desc` in this scope?

Comment: You're grouping by years and months yet you try to sort by date, how would that work? Just sort by the year and month.

Comment: @JakubKania I need to sort groups by customer order date, from newest to oldest.

Comment: You can't -- the group by aggregated away the date. You need to introduce a sub query with the individual orders. Scope is probably not the place to do this.

Comment: @SsPay but you have multiple dates withing the group, which one do you need?